# Data Processing Inequality for Random Vectors forming a Markov Chain

Tags: markov-chains, information-theory, entropy, mutual-information

Suppose 3 $n$-length random vectors form a Markov chain: $\mathbf{X} \rightarrow \mathbf{Y} \rightarrow \mathbf{Z}$. Moreover, $Y_{i}$ is a deterministic function of $Z_{i}$ (ie. $Y_{i}=g_{i}(Z_{i})$).

Does the inequality
\begin{align}
I(\mathbf{X};\mathbf{Z}) \leq I(\mathbf{X};\mathbf{Y})
\end{align}
still hold? If not, what are the other properties that need to be satisfied in order for the above inequality to be true?

I tried the following approach:

\begin{align}
I(\mathbf{X};\mathbf{Z}) =& \sum_{i = 1}^{n} I(\mathbf{X};Z_i|Z_{1}^{i-1})\\
= & \sum_{i = 1}^{n} H(\mathbf{X}|Z_{1}^{i-1}) - H(\mathbf{X}|Z_{i},Z_{1}^{i-1})\\
\leq & \sum_{i = 1}^{n} H(\mathbf{X}|Z_{1}^{i-1}) - H(\mathbf{X}|Y_{i},Z_{i},Z_{1}^{i-1})\\
= & \sum_{i = 1}^{n} H(\mathbf{X}|Z_{1}^{i-1}) - H(\mathbf{X}|Y_{i},Z_{1}^{i-1})\\
= & \sum_{i = 1}^{n} I(\mathbf{X};Y_{i}|Z_{1}^{i-1}).
\end{align}

However, I'm stuck and not sure how to proceed with this (or if there are other conditions that need to be satisfied in order for the inequality to be true). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The definitions of entropy, mutual information, etc for discrete random variables are not specific to one-dimensional (scalar) quantities. They apply also to multi-dimensional variables, with no changes. Hence it's true that
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{X} \rightarrow \mathbf{Y} \rightarrow \mathbf{Z} \implies I(\mathbf{X};\mathbf{Z}) \leq I(\mathbf{X};\mathbf{Y})
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you for confirming that Data Processing Inequality still works for random vectors. However, I'm not sure how to prove it rigorously. Could you give me some hints on how to show this? Currently, I have shown that $I(\mathbf{X};\mathbf{Z}) \leq \sum_{i = 1}^n I(\mathbf{X};Y_{i}|Z_{1}^{i-1})$. But What I need is  $I(\mathbf{X};\mathbf{Z}) \leq \sum_{i = 1}^n I(\mathbf{X};Y_{i}|Y_{1}^{i-1})$

Comment: No, sorry. If you have proved rigorously the inequality for scalar random variables, you only need to check that all the steps (starting from the definition of entropy) apply with zero changes to vectors. That's trivial.